# How to refresh the ticket after 30 minutes automatically?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, access-token, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net5

The customer told me that after 30 minutes continuous using the web, an error pops up, saying:

> "An error has occurred! Error detail not sent by server."

I checked the source code, and found it should be caused by `ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc` property which was set to 30 minutes. How to refresh the ticket after 30 minutes automatically?

The 30 minutes limitation is in `Authenticate` of **webapi/api/controllers/AccountController.cs**.

The stack trace is as below:

```
WARN  2018-09-24 00:47:42,673 [25   ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Current user did not login to the application!
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<CheckPermissions>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelperExtensions.Authorize(IAuthorizationHelper authorizationHelper, MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
   at Abp.Web.Mvc.Authorization.AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Current user did not login to the application!
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<CheckPermissions>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelperExtensions.Authorize(IAuthorizationHelper authorizationHelper, MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
   at Abp.Web.Mvc.Authorization.AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

Comment: add a timer with 25 mins interval. authenticate it in every ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SlidingExpiration** is only available for cookies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration?view=netframework-4.7.2

In general, sliding expiration for **accessToken** is wrong - once **accessToken** is leaked, it can be used to indefinitely prolong the access.
That's what a refresh token is for. ABP does not handle refresh tokens but you can refer to IdentityServer4's [Token Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html).
Note that refresh token also has to be handled client-side: when you receive 401 Error, call the endpoint, then set to new **accessToken**.

If you decide to do sliding expiration, here's a third-party document on [Reissusing a JWT with a New (Sliding) Expiration](https://github.com/jacobslusser/JwtAuthRenewWebApi/blob/9fa8819e534b5434dd4ff3e8ae1c0dd1d6afd364/docs/Sliding-Expiration.md) for WebApi.